# When i rotate root bone or the whole armature by selecting all bones this weird deformation happens in the toe?

Tags: armature

this are the image. first image is frame 1. second image is frame 100. third image is frame 67

[image: frame 1]

[image: frame 100]

[image: frame 67]

Comment: Looks like something with the bone weights.  Could you please show a screenshot of the wait painting please?

Comment: which bones weight u want to see? i will put a screen shot of it

Comment: Go through your vertex groups and check to make sure the parts of the foot that are deforming weirdly are only assigned to one bone.